# Why "def tokenize(text)"? Relating to count occurrences of a string inside text

Tags: python

I feel disgraced by asking about the solution of my "homework" here. But I have already spent 4 hours on it, cannot continue like this.

**Assignment:** count occurrences of a specific string inside a Lorem Ipsum text (already given); a helper function tokenize that splits a given text and returns a list of tokens has been provided.

```
def tokenize(text):
    return text.split()

for token in tokenize(text):
    print(token)
```

Task: Write a function `search_text()` which takes two parameters in this order: `filename` and `query`.

The function should return the number of occurrences of `query` inside the file `filename`.

```
query = 'ipsum'
search_text('lorem-ipsum.txt', query) # returns 24
```

---

My code:

```
def tokenize(text):
    return text.split()

def search_text(filename, query):
    with open("lorem-ipsum.txt", "r") as filename:
      wordlist = filename.split()
      count = 0
   for query in wordlist:
      count = count + 1
   return count

query = "lorem"
search_text('lorem-ipsum.txt', query)
```

It doesn't work and looks a little bit mess. To be honst, I don't unterstand how the function `tokenize()` works here.

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: The function takes an input string `text`, runs `text.split()`, and returns the resulting list (it is a list of words in that string, in this example). In your code it does nothing, because you do not ever call `tokenize()`.

Comment: Maybe take a step back from the code for a second. How would you go about solving this by hand, if you were given a string of characters and told to find a specific string?

Comment: Hey @CJ59 Thank you very much for the explanation. I also tried:  "for query in tokenize(filename)". Still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to call the function `tokenize()` if you want to use it; your code does not.

This version could work:

```
def tokenize(text):
    return text.split()

def search_text(filename, query):
    word_list = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) > 0:
                # add tokens to the list, only if line is not empty
                wordlist.extend(tokenize(line))

    count = 0
    for word in word_list:
        if word == query:
            count += 1

    return count

query = "lorem"
search_text('lorem-ipsum.txt', query)
```

---

You could also use other counting methods, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2600191/9225671) shows. Here is a solution using the [`.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method of sequences:

```
return word_list.count(query)
```